# Criar trigger automaticamente

Tags: javascript, mysql

Eu criei um código que cria uma `trigger` automaticamente para MySQL.

Porém minha função ainda tem falhas, uma delas é que está aceitando as declarações de `PK's` e `FK's` como se fossem campos da tabela.

Vejam essa declaração de uma tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE `pedidos` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `data` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '1000-01-01',
    `hora` TIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00',
    `conta_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `contato_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `empresa_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `nome_oportunidade` VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
    `tipo_oportunidade_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `subtipo_oportunidade_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `status_oportunidade_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `tarefa_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `status_entrega_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',   
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `Com_Contas` (`conta_id`),
    INDEX `Com_Tipos_Acao` (`tipo_oportunidade_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_oportunidade_tarefa` FOREIGN KEY (`tarefa_id`) REFERENCES `tarefas` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `oportunidadeComStatusEntrega` FOREIGN KEY (`status_entrega_id`) REFERENCES `entrega_status` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL,
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=666666
;
```

Utilizando de uma expressão regular eu busco todos os campos da tabela:

```
/`(\w*)`/g;
```

Vejam meu código:

```html
<html>
  <head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function gerar(){
          var conteudo = document.formTabela.conteudo.value;
          var reg = /`(\w*)`/g;

          var res = conteudo.match(reg);
          criarTriggerInsert(res);
        }

        function criarTriggerInsert(arr){
          var tabela = arr.shift();
          tabela = tabela.replace(/`/g, '');
          var createTrigger = `CREATE TRIGGER trg_${tabela}_01
                                AFTER INSERT ON ${tabela}
                                 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

                                 INSERT INTO historico_tabela (
                                 operacao,
                                 data_acao,
                                 hora_acao,
                                 tabela,
                                 campo_id,
                                 usuario_insercao,
                                 usuario_alteracao,
                                 campo,
                                 valor_anterior,
                                 valor_atual
                                ) VALUES `;
          for( campo in arr ){
             var campoTabela = arr[campo].replace(/`/g, '');

             createTrigger += ` ( 'insert',
                                CURDATE(),
                                CURTIME(),
                                '${tabela}',
                                NEW.id,
                                @usuario_historico,
                                NULL,
                                '${campoTabela}',
                                NULL,
                                NEW.${campoTabela}
                               ),`;

          }

          createTrigger = createTrigger.substring(0,createTrigger.length -1);

          console.log(createTrigger);

        }

     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <form name="formTabela" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
        <label>DDL:</label><br>
        <textarea name="conteudo" cols="100" rows="5"></textarea><br>
        <button onclick="gerar();">Gerar Trigger</button>
      <form/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Executando com base no `DDL` acima, consigo gerar o resultado mais ou menos esperado, vejam o resultado da execução:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_pedidos_01
 AFTER INSERT ON pedidos
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN



INSERT INTO historico_tabela (
                                        operacao,
                                        data_acao,
                                        hora_acao,
                                        tabela,
                                        campo_id,
                                        usuario_insercao,
                                        usuario_alteracao,
                                        campo,
                                        valor_anterior,
                                        valor_atual
                                    ) VALUES  ( 'insert',
                                         CURDATE(),
                                         CURTIME(),
                                         'pedidos',
                                         NEW.id,
                                         @usuario_historico,
                                         NULL,
                                         'id',
                                         NULL,
                                         NEW.id
                                   ), ( 'insert',
                                         CURDATE(),
                                         CURTIME(),
                                         'pedidos',
                                         NEW.id,
                                         @usuario_historico,
                                         NULL,
                                         'data',
                                         NULL,
                                         NEW.data
                                   ), ( 'insert',
                                         CURDATE(),
                                         CURTIME(),
                                         'pedidos',
                                         NEW.id,
                                         @usuario_historico,
                                         NULL,
                                         'hora',
                                         NULL,
                                         NEW.hora
                                   ), ( 'insert',
                                         CURDATE(),
                                         CURTIME(),
                                         'pedidos',
                                         NEW.id,
                                         @usuario_historico,
                                         NULL,
                                         'conta_id',
                                         NULL,
                                         NEW.conta_id
                                   ), ( 'insert',
                                         CURDATE(),
                                         CURTIME(),
                                         'pedidos',
                                         NEW.id,
                                         @usuario_historico,
                                         NULL,
                                         'contato_id',
                                         NULL,
                                         NEW.contato_id
                                   ), ( 'insert',
                                         CURDATE(),
                                         CURTIME(),
                                         'pedidos',
                                         NEW.id,
                                         @usuario_historico,
                                         NULL,
                                         'empresa_id',
                                         NULL,
                                         NEW.empresa_id
                                   ), ( 'insert',
                                         CURDATE(),
                                         CURTIME(),
                                         'pedidos',
                                         NEW.id,
                                         @usuario_historico,
                                         NULL,
                                         'nome_oportunidade',
                                         NULL,
                                         NEW.nome_oportunidade
                                   ), ( 'insert',
                                         CURDATE(),
                                         CURTIME(),
                                         'pedidos',
                                         NEW.id,
                                         @usuario_historico,
                                         NULL,
                                         'tipo_oportunidade_id',
                                         NULL,
                                         NEW.tipo_oportunidade_id
                                   ), ( 'insert',
                                         CURDATE(),
                                         CURTIME(),
                                         'pedidos',
                                         NEW.id,
                                         @usuario_historico,
                                         NULL,
                                         'subtipo_oportunidade_id',
                                         NULL,
                                         NEW.subtipo_oportunidade_id
                                   ), ( 'insert',
                                         CURDATE(),
                                         CURTIME(),
                                         'pedidos',
                                         NEW.id,
                                         @usuario_historico,
                                         NULL,
                                         'status_oportunidade_id',
                                         NULL,
                                         NEW.status_oportunidade_id
                                   ), ( 'insert',
                                         CURDATE(),
                                         CURTIME(),
                                         'pedidos',
                                         NEW.id,
                                         @usuario_historico,
                                         NULL,
                                         'tarefa_id',
                                         NULL,
                                         NEW.tarefa_id
                                   ), ( 'insert',
                                         CURDATE(),
                                         CURTIME(),
                                         'pedidos',
                                         NEW.id,
                                         @usuario_historico,
                                         NULL,
                                         'status_entrega_id',
                                         NULL,
                                         NEW.status_entrega_id
                                   ), ( 'insert',
                                         CURDATE(),
                                         CURTIME(),
                                         'pedidos',
                                         NEW.id,
                                         @usuario_historico,
                                         NULL,
                                         'id',
                                         NULL,
                                         NEW.id
                                   ), ( 'insert',
                                         CURDATE(),
                                         CURTIME(),
                                         'pedidos',
                                         NEW.id,
                                         @usuario_historico,
                                         NULL,
                                         'Com_Contas',
                                         NULL,
                                         NEW.Com_Contas
                                   ), ( 'insert',
                                         CURDATE(),
                                         CURTIME(),
                                         'pedidos',
                                         NEW.id,
                                         @usuario_historico,
                                         NULL,
                                         'conta_id',
                                         NULL,
                                         NEW.conta_id
                                   ), ( 'insert',
                                         CURDATE(),
                                         CURTIME(),
                                         'pedidos',
                                         NEW.id,
                                         @usuario_historico,
                                         NULL,
                                         'Com_Tipos_Acao',
                                         NULL,
                                         NEW.Com_Tipos_Acao
                                   ), ( 'insert',
                                         CURDATE(),
                                         CURTIME(),
                                         'pedidos',
                                         NEW.id,
                                         @usuario_historico,
                                         NULL,
                                         'tipo_oportunidade_id',
                                         NULL,
                                         NEW.tipo_oportunidade_id
                                   ), ( 'insert',
                                         CURDATE(),
                                         CURTIME(),
                                         'pedidos',
                                         NEW.id,
                                         @usuario_historico,
                                         NULL,
                                         'fk_oportunidade_tarefa',
                                         NULL,
                                         NEW.fk_oportunidade_tarefa
                                   ), ( 'insert',
                                         CURDATE(),
                                         CURTIME(),
                                         'pedidos',
                                         NEW.id,
                                         @usuario_historico,
                                         NULL,
                                         'tarefa_id',
                                         NULL,
                                         NEW.tarefa_id
                                   ), ( 'insert',
                                         CURDATE(),
                                         CURTIME(),
                                         'pedidos',
                                         NEW.id,
                                         @usuario_historico,
                                         NULL,
                                         'tarefas',
                                         NULL,
                                         NEW.tarefas
                                   ), ( 'insert',
                                         CURDATE(),
                                         CURTIME(),
                                         'pedidos',
                                         NEW.id,
                                         @usuario_historico,
                                         NULL,
                                         'id',
                                         NULL,
                                         NEW.id
                                   ), ( 'insert',
                                         CURDATE(),
                                         CURTIME(),
                                         'pedidos',
                                         NEW.id,
                                         @usuario_historico,
                                         NULL,
                                         'oportunidadeComStatusEntrega',
                                         NULL,
                                         NEW.oportunidadeComStatusEntrega
                                   ), ( 'insert',
                                         CURDATE(),
                                         CURTIME(),
                                         'pedidos',
                                         NEW.id,
                                         @usuario_historico,
                                         NULL,
                                         'status_entrega_id',
                                         NULL,
                                         NEW.status_entrega_id
                                   ), ( 'insert',
                                         CURDATE(),
                                         CURTIME(),
                                         'pedidos',
                                         NEW.id,
                                         @usuario_historico,
                                         NULL,
                                         'entrega_status',
                                         NULL,
                                         NEW.entrega_status
                                   ), ( 'insert',
                                         CURDATE(),
                                         CURTIME(),
                                         'pedidos',
                                         NEW.id,
                                         @usuario_historico,
                                         NULL,
                                         'id',
                                         NULL,
                                         NEW.id
                                   );
```

Mas vejam, não está certo essa trigger. Pois está repetindo os campos:

```
(`id`),
(`conta_id`)
(`tipo_oportunidade_id`)
(`tarefa_id`)
(`id`)
(`status_entrega_id`)
```

E localizando os nomes dos Index, Contraint e nome de tabela como se fosse campo:

```
INDEX `Com_Contas` ,
INDEX `Com_Tipos_Acao` ,
CONSTRAINT `fk_oportunidade_tarefa` 
REFERENCES `tarefas` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `oportunidadeComStatusEntrega` 
REFERENCES `entrega_status`
```

**Como faço para não considerar essa parte que está no DDL?**

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `Com_Contas` (`conta_id`),
    INDEX `Com_Tipos_Acao` (`tipo_oportunidade_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_oportunidade_tarefa` FOREIGN KEY (`tarefa_id`) REFERENCES `tarefas` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `oportunidadeComStatusEntrega` FOREIGN KEY (`status_entrega_id`) REFERENCES `entrega_status` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL,
```

Isso está acontecendo devido a minha expressão regular buscar os CAMPOS da tabela que estejam entre `aspas`, porém está trazendo campos que na verdade não são campos.

Comment: Qual exatamente o seu objetivo e a sua dúvida?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo devido a expressão regular buscar todos os campos que estejam entre as aspas simples, estava buscando o campo `id` lá na declaração da PK. Com isso estava carregando 2 vezes esse campo na hora de montar a trigger. como você pode ver no código fonte. Mas consegui resolver através de uma "quebra" (`\n`) antes de usar a expressão regular.

Comment: Melhorei o texto, ficou compreensível?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depois de algumas buscas, encontrei uma solução que atende o que eu necessito resolver.

Fiz diretamente no JavaScript algumas alterações que solucionaram o meu problema.

Antes de usar a expressão regular, quebrei o texto em um array e percorri ele atrás das palavras reservadas **PRIMARY KEY**, **INDEX** e **FOREIGN KEY**.
Caso encontrar essas palavras eu removo do array, depois eu junto o array novamente e faço o restante do que eu já fazia.

Deixo o código corrigido para utilização da comunidade.

```html
<html>
  <head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function gerar(){
          var conteudo = document.formTabela.conteudo.value;
          var reg = /`(\w*)`/g;

          conteudo = conteudo.split('\n');

          var primary = 'NAO_LOCALIZADO';

          for(linha in conteudo){
            if(conteudo[linha].toLowerCase().indexOf('primary key') !== -1){
              primary = conteudo[linha].match(reg);
              primary = primary[0].replace(/`/g, '');

              delete conteudo[linha];
            } else if(conteudo[linha].toLowerCase().indexOf('index `') !== -1 || conteudo[linha].toLowerCase().indexOf('foreign key') !== -1){
              delete conteudo[linha];
            }
          }

          conteudo = conteudo.join('\n');

          var res = conteudo.match(reg);
          criarTriggerInsert(res, primary);
          criarTriggerUpdate(res, primary);
        }

        function criarTriggerInsert(arr, primary){
          var tabela = arr.shift();
          tabela = tabela.replace(/`/g, '');
          var createTrigger = `DELIMITER //
                                CREATE TRIGGER trg_${tabela}_01
                                  AFTER INSERT ON ${tabela}
                                   FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

                                   INSERT INTO historico_tabela (
                                   operacao,
                                   data_acao,
                                   hora_acao,
                                   tabela,
                                   campo_id,
                                   usuario_insercao,
                                   usuario_alteracao,
                                   campo,
                                   valor_anterior,
                                   valor_atual
                                  ) VALUES `;
          for( campo in arr ){
             var campoTabela = arr[campo].replace(/`/g, '');

             if(campoTabela != primary) {
               createTrigger += ` ( 'insert',
                                  CURDATE(),
                                  CURTIME(),
                                  '${tabela}',
                                  NEW.${primary},
                                  @usuario_historico,
                                  NULL,
                                  '${campoTabela}',
                                  NULL,
                                  NEW.${campoTabela}
                                 ),`;
              }
          }

          createTrigger = createTrigger.substring(0,createTrigger.length -1);

          createTrigger = createTrigger + `;
          END //`;

          document.formTabela.conteudo_resultado_insert.value = createTrigger;

        }

        function criarTriggerUpdate(arr, primary){
          var tabela = arr.shift();
          tabela = tabela.replace(/`/g, '');
          var createTrigger = `DELIMITER //
                                CREATE TRIGGER trg_${tabela}_02
                                  BEFORE UPDATE ON ${tabela}
                                   FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
                              `;
          for( campo in arr ){

             var campoTabela = arr[campo].replace(/`/g, '');

             if(campoTabela != primary){

               createTrigger += ` IF( OLD.${campoTabela} <> NEW.${campoTabela} ) THEN
                    INSERT INTO historico_tabela (
                       operacao,
                       data_acao,
                       hora_acao,
                       tabela,
                       campo_id,
                       usuario_insercao,
                       usuario_alteracao,
                       campo,
                       valor_anterior,
                       valor_atual
                     ) VALUES (
                       'update',
                       CURDATE(),
                       CURTIME(),
                       '${tabela}',
                       NEW.${primary},
                       NULL,
                       @usuario_historico,
                       '${campoTabela}',
                       OLD.${campoTabela},
                       NEW.${campoTabela}
                     );
                   END IF;

               `;
              }
          }

          createTrigger = createTrigger + `  END //`;

          document.formTabela.conteudo_resultado_update.value = createTrigger;
        }

     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <form name="formTabela" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
        <label>DDL:</label><br>
        <textarea name="conteudo" cols="100" rows="5"></textarea><br>
        <button onclick="gerar();">Gerar Trigger</button><br><br>
        <label>Resultado Insert:</label><br>
        <textarea name="conteudo_resultado_insert" cols="100" rows="5"></textarea><br>
        <label>Resultado Update:</label><br>
        <textarea name="conteudo_resultado_update" cols="100" rows="5"></textarea><br>
      <form/>
  </body>
</html>
```